# In saltstack, how do I conditionally, and iteratively ( jinja ) apply an included state

Tags: salt-stack, jinja2

This may seem at first to be pretty simple.  But I can tell you I've been wracking my brains for a couple days on this.  I've read a lot of docs, sat on IRC with folks, and spoken to colleagues and at this point I don't have an answer I really think holds up.

I've looked into a few possible approaches

- reactor
- orchestration runner

I don't like these two because of the top down execution necessity... they seem tailored to orchestrating multiple node states, not workflows in a single node.

- custom states

This is kind of something I would REALLY like to avoid as this is a repeated workflow, and I don't want to build customizations like this.  There's too much room for non legibility if I go down this path with my team mates.

- requires / watches

These don't have a concept ( that I am aware of ) of applying a state repeatedly, or in a logical order / workflow.

And a few others I won't mention.

Without further discussion, here's my dilemma.

Goals:

- Jenkins Master gets Deployed
- We can unit.test the deployment as it proceeds
- We only restart tomcat when necessary
- We can update plugins on a per package basis
- A big emphasis on good clean intuitively clear salt configs

Jenkins deployment is pretty straight forward.  We drop in the packages, and the configs, and we're set.

Unit testing is harder.  As an example I've got this state file.

actions/version.sls:

```
# Hit's the jenkins CLI interface to check for version info
# This can be used to verify that jenkins is active and the version we want

# Import some info
{%- from 'jenkins/init.sls' import jenkins_home with context %}

# Install plugins in jenkins_plugins list
jenkins_version:
  cmd.run:
    - name: java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s "http://127.0.0.1:8080" version
    - cwd: /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/
    - user: jenkins
```

actions.version basically verifies that jenkins is running and queryable.  we want to be sure of this during the build at several points.

example... tomcat takes time to spin up.  we had to add a delay to that restart operation.  If you check out start.sls below you can see that operation occurring.  Note the bug open on init_delay: .

actions/start.sls:

```
# Starts the tomcat service
tomcat_start:
  service.running:
    - name: tomcat
    - enable: True
    - full_restart: True
# Not functional atm see --> https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/20631
#    - init_delay: 120

# initiate a 120 second delay after any service start to let tomcat come up.
tomcat_wait:
  module.run:
    - name: test.sleep
    - length: 60

include:
  - jenkins.actions.version
```

Now we have this restart capability by doing an actions.stop and an actions.start.  We have this actions.version state that we can use to verify that the system is ready to proceed with jenkins specific state workflows.

I want to do something kinda like this...

```
 Install Jenkins --> Grab yaml of plugins --> install plugins that need it
```

Pretty straight forward.

Except, to loop through the yaml of plugins I am using Jinja.
And now I have no way to call and be sure that the start.sls and version.sls states can be repeatedly applied.

I am looking for, a good way to do that.

This would be something akin to a jenkins.sls

```
{% set repo_username = "foo" -%}
{% set repo_password = "bar" -%}

include:
  - jenkins.actions.version
  - jenkins.actions.stop
  - jenkins.actions.start

# Install Jenkins
jenkins:
  pkg:
    - installed

# Import Jenkins Plugins as List, and Working Path
{%- from 'jenkins/init.sls' import jenkins_home with context %}
{%- import_yaml "jenkins/plugins.sls" as jenkins_plugins %}
{%- import_yaml "jenkins/custom-plugins.sls" as custom_plugins %}
# Grab updated package list
jenkins-contact-update-server:
  cmd.run:
    - name: curl -L http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json | sed '1d;$d' > {{ jenkins_home }}/updates/default.json
    - unless: test -d {{ jenkins_home }}/updates/default.json
    - require:
      - pkg: jenkins
      - service: tomcat
# Install plugins in jenkins_plugins list
{% for plugin in jenkins_plugins %}
jenkins-plugin-{{ plugin }}:
  cmd.run:
    - name: java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s "http://127.0.0.1:8080" install-plugin "{{ plugin }}"
    - unless: java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s "http://127.0.0.1:8080" list-plugins | grep "{{ plugin }}"
    - cwd: /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/
    - user: jenkins
    - require:
      - pkg: jenkins
      - service: tomcat
```

Here is where I am stuck.  require won't do this.  and lists 
of actions don't seem to schedule linearly in salt.  I need to
be able to just verify that jenkins is up and ready.  I need 
to be able to restart tomcat after a single plugin in the 
iteration is added.  I need to be able to do this to satisfy 
dependencies in the plugin order.

```
      - sls: jenkins.actions.version
      - sls: jenkins.actions.stop
      - sls: jenkins.actions.start
#    This can't work for several reasons
#    - watch_in:
#      - sls: jenkins-safe-restart
{% endfor %}

# Install custom plugins in the custom_plugins list
{% for cust_plugin,cust_plugin_url in custom_plugins.iteritems() %}
# manually downloading the plugin, because jenkins-cli.jar doesn't seem to work direct to artifactory URLs.
download-plugin-{{ cust_plugin }}:
  cmd.run:
    - name: curl -o {{ cust_plugin }}.jpi -O "https://{{ repo_username }}:{{ repo_password }}@{{ cust_plugin_url }}"
    - unless: java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s "http://127.0.0.1:8080" list-plugins | grep "{{ cust_plugin }}"
    - cwd: /tmp
    - user: jenkins
    - require:
      - pkg: jenkins
      - service: tomcat
# installing the plugin ( REQUIRES TOMCAT RESTART AFTER )
custom-plugin-{{ cust_plugin }}:
  cmd.run:
    - name: java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s "http://127.0.0.1:8080" install-plugin /tmp/{{ cust_plugin }}.jpi
    - unless: java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s "http://127.0.0.1:8080" list-plugins | grep "{{ cust_plugin }}"
    - cwd: /var/lib/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/
    - user: jenkins
    - require:
      - pkg: jenkins
      - service: tomcat
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3):

You won't be able to achieve this without using reactors, beacons and especially not without writing your own python execution modules.

> Jenkins Master gets Deployed

Write a jenkins execution module in python with a function `install(...):`. In that function you would manage any dependencies by either calling existing execution modules or by writing them yourself.

> We can unit.test the deployment as it proceeds

Inside the install function of the jenkins module you would fire specific [events](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/develop/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.event.html#module-salt.modules.event) depending on the results of the install.

```
if not _run_deployment_phase(...):
    __salt__['event.send']('jenkins/install/error', {
            'finished': False,
            'message': "Something failed during the deployment!",
    })
```

You would [map that event to reactor sls files](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/develop/topics/reactor/index.html#mapping-events-to-reactor-sls-files) and handle it.

> We only restart tomcat when necessary

Write a tomcat module. Add an `_is_up(...)` function where you would check if tomcat is up by parsing the tomcat logs for the result. Call the function inside a state module and add a mod_watch function.

```
def mod_watch():
    # required dict to return
    return_dict = {
           "name": "Tomcat install",
           "changes": {}, 
           "result": False,
           "comment": "",
            }
    if __salt__["tomcat._is_up"]():
      return_dict["result"] = True
      return_dict["comment"] = "Tomcat is up."

    if __opts__["test"]:
        return_dict["result"] = None
        return_dict["comment"] = "comment here about what will change"
        return return_dict

    # execute changes now

    return return_dict
```

Use your state module inside a state file.

```
install tomcat:
  tomcat.install:
    - name: ...
    - user: ...
    ...

wait until tomcat is up:
  cmd.run:
    - name: ...
    - watch:
      - tomcat: install tomcat
```

> We can update plugins on a per package basis

Add a function to your jenkins execution module named install_plugin. View pkg.install code to replicate interface.

> A big emphasis on good clean intuitively clear salt configs

Write python execution modules for easy and maintainable configuration logic. Use that execution module inside your own state modules. Inside state files call your own state modules and supply individual configuration with any state renderer you like.

Comment: So basically, don't use salt.

Comment: Writing your own modules and using the reactor is using salt. If you look at the source code of salts existing modules you see that everything is built upon execution modules which are used in state modules. You could easily implement in one module all your steps and use python to make the required API requests to jenkins and check if a service is up via the existing modules or check if you get a known http response from tomcat which would allow you to easily handle errors which would be annoying with jinja alone.

Answer (score 0):

States only execute once, by design. If you need the same action to occur multiple times, you need multiple states. Also, includes are only included a single time.

Rather than all of this include/require stuff you're doing, you should just put all of the code into a single sls file, and generate states through jinja iteration.

If what you're trying to do is add a bunch of plugins, add config files, then at the end do restarts, then you should really just execute everything in order, don't use require, and use listen or listen_in, rather than watch or watch_in.

listen/listen_in cause triggered actions to happen at the end of a state run. They are similar to the concept of handlers in Ansible.

Comment: I need to do conditional restarts DURING the plugin additions to satisfy a network of cross dependencies in the plugins.  Not at the end.  And conditional is a big point, I don't want to restart unless certain unit tests verify the need.  I also want to wait during state applications.  listen_in won't work with SLS, listen won't achieve my goals.  Being unable to share SLS files defeats the goal of reusable clean code.

Comment: Reusable clean code is overrated in config management and is generally a waste of time: http://ryandlane.com/blog/2014/10/08/config-management-code-reuse-isnt-always-the-right-approach/

Comment: What you're trying to accomplish is possible. We're doing this with jenkins right now, but the way in which you're trying to approach it is quite difficult, no matter which config management system you use. You could use jinja functions to make this more modular, where you pass in the name of the plugin and it generates the relevant states, along with service restart commands. Note that you'll need to use cmd.wait for restarts, rather than triggering the service definition directly.

Comment: I disagree with your approach immensely.  It just does not scale.

Comment: Are you installing multiple jenkins servers with different configurations? If not, what's the point of making the code generic? It doesn't make it more scalable because you won't be reusing it anyway. The point of clean re-usable code is to re-use it.

Comment: Yes I am.  And Slaves.  Many dynamic slaves.  Also this is tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty old question, but If you change your Jenkins/tomcat start/stop procedure to be a standard init/systemd/windows service (as all well behaved services should be), you could have a service.running for the Jenkins service and add this to each of your custom-plugin-{{ cust_plugin }} states.

```
require_in: 
  - svc: jenkins
watch_in: 
  - svc: jenkins
```

You could continue to use the cmd.run module with onchanges. You'd have to add onchanges_in: to each of the custom-plugin-{{ cust_plugin }} states, but you need to have at least one item in the on changes list or the command will fire every time the state runs.

Answer (score -1):

If you use require you cause salt to re-order your states. If you want your states to run in order, just write them in the order you want them to run in.

Watch/watch_in will also re-order your states. If you use listen/listen_in instead, it'll queue the triggered actions to run in the order they were triggered at the end of the state run.

See:

http://ryandlane.com/blog/2014/07/14/truly-ordered-execution-using-saltstack/
http://ryandlane.com/blog/2015/01/06/truly-ordered-execution-using-saltstack-part-2/

Comment: you can't call an sls file (directly), and I did attempt to do something akin to a no-op to call the sls state.  this didn't work either.  and if my understanding is correct it may be because of how the state applications are scheduled... I think once a state is applied, inside of a given state, it just sort of assumes it's been applied forever.